# Looping function works 20 times in javascript, but then returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

```
run = 0
function getLowestPrice(id){
   $.get('/items/' + id + '/privatesaleslist', function(data){
      var html = $(data);
      var lowestPrice = parseInt($('.currency-robux', html).eq(0).text().replace(',', ''));
      console.log(lowestPrice);
   })
}
while (run < 100) 
{
getLowestPrice(362081769);
run = run + 1
}
```

Webpage I am using this code on: https://m.roblox.com/items/362081769

What happens is when I run this code it runs successfully 20 times returning 3997, and then I get spammed with "NaN" [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCOLE.png).

What i'm trying to get this program to do is check the price of the item for as long as I want, and report it in the chrome console. Why does the function work 20 times and then just return NaN?

I am a beginner at javascript, so please explain your solutions so a beginner like me can understand.

Thanks :)

Comment: look at the data returned in each `$.get` in the developer tools network tab - is it correct?

Comment: you're making an async call in your loop, which will continue execution.  i think you probably want to increment your run var inside the callback of your $.get.  console.log(run) inside your callback to see the weirdness.

Comment: @JaromandX I found the problem! Roblox doesn't like me giving this many requests, so after 20 it shuts off the feed to me. Is there a way around it?

Comment: @ant how do I increment it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey man I think part of your issue is in the while loop mechanic.  Whenever run hits 100 your function will stop being called.

You could use a setInterval function.  How this work is it will call whichever function you pass it, every "x" milliseconds.

setInterval will call getLowestPrice with the id of 362081769, every 5 seconds.

```
const id = 362081769
function getLowestPrice(){
  $.get('/items/' + id + '/privatesaleslist', function(data){
  var html = $(data);
  var lowestPrice = parseInt($('.currency-robux', html).eq(0).text().replace(',', ''));
  console.log(lowestPrice);
 })
}

setInterval(getLowestPrice, 5000);
```

Also here is a link to the formal setInterval documentation. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Wow this is actually pretty useful! I think another one of the problems is that roblox doesn't like me requesting the privatesale list so many times. Is there anyway I can get around this?

Comment: Which is definitely normal.  Whenever you work with a foreign API they will often restrict the amount of requests that you can make.

Currently the setInterval is set to run every 5 seconds at 5000.  You could increase that value to whatever you want. 30000 would be every 30 seconds. 60000 would be every minute.  600000 would be once every 10 minutes.

If you found this useful or helpful, don't be afraid to upvote the answer.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for the help! This will definitely help!